# Getting 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT after changing SMTP credential digital ocean droplet

Tags: node.js, smtp, digital-ocean, nodemailer, droplet

I came across on MERN stack web app which is deploy on Digital Ocean Droplet.

It has some SMTP credential issues, i found the right credential , test in my local host. It's working smoothly.
When I make the same changing in my digital ocean droplet server, it's throwing ERROR  504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT 'api.link/'.

I have .env file , where I updated SMTP credential

How can i fix this issues?
[image: Error snap]